# Customizing Twitter Digits in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, twitter-digits

I want to customize the content of the  sms verification sent by twitter digits . I want to customize the title of the sms with the name of my app instead of TA-TWITTR And Can I use twitter digits as sms API for inviting users to use my app ?? Im Using digits in Swift Ios . Thank You

Comment: Agree with you. At least it should show the application name in the SMS. Otherwise how users know which application this SMS is for?

Answer (score 1):

Digits PM here - it's not possible to change the name of the sender but you can set an app name to appear in the SMS by going to your app's Digits tab on the fabric.io dashboard and editing the Application Name.

If you need any assistance feel free to reach out: @chrisoryschak.

Comment: @VinothKrishnand Why doesn't this answer the question?